# Find alternative value if no no valid data is found on a specific column on joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I have a SQL query with a number of joined tables that return contract data for employees that are valid from a given date.
An example result would be as follows:

```
 EmployeeID   Validfrom    ContractType  ContractedHours   PayRate   Role
 ABC123       01/01/2015     Hourly            24          $11.52    Waiter
 ABC123       01/04/2015     Hourly            24          $12.63    TeamLeader
 ABC123       01/01/2016     Hourly            32          $12.98    NULL
```

In the above results you would have 3 separate revisions of the contract however on the latest revision of the contract the role did not change and the result was returned `NULL`. How can I return the most recent valid result on any of these fields where the result is `NULL` so the last line would show

```
 EmployeeID   Validfrom    ContractType  ContractedHours   PayRate   Role
 ABC123       01/01/2016     Hourly            32          $12.98    TeamLeader
```

Comment: Please show your query...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a SQL Server 2008 instance available to test. With databases supporting Window Function this is very easy...

If you have a table like this:

```
SQL> select * from vdata order by vfrom;
 empid  |   vfrom    | ctype  | chours | prate |    role    
--------+------------+--------+--------+-------+------------
 ABC123 | 2015-01-01 | Hourly |     24 | 11.52 | Waiter
 ABC123 | 2015-01-04 | Hourly |     24 | 12.63 | TeamLeader
 ABC123 | 2016-01-01 | Hourly |     32 | 12.98 | (null)
```

You just have to:

```
SQL> select empid, vfrom, ctype, chours, prate, 
            last_value(role ignore nulls) 
               over(partition by empid order by vfrom) as role 
     from vdata ;
 empid  |   vfrom    | ctype  | chours | prate |    role    
--------+------------+--------+--------+-------+------------
 ABC123 | 2015-01-01 | Hourly |     24 | 11.52 | Waiter
 ABC123 | 2015-01-04 | Hourly |     24 | 12.63 | TeamLeader
 ABC123 | 2016-01-01 | Hourly |     32 | 12.98 | TeamLeader
```

The key part is the last element in the select list: it will get the last value of the role column (ignoring nulls) with data partitioned by empid and ordered by validity date. In other words... last non null value for each employee.